# Count distinct attribute values based on two other columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

I've got a table with three key attributes, like below:

[image: Input Table]

I want to query it to figure out the number of items sold based on item type and date sold. So the output might look something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/27glz.png]

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT SaleItem AS 'Item Sold', SaleDay AS 'Item Sell Day', COUNT(DISTINCT SaleNumber) AS 'Number'
FROM Sales
GROUP BY SaleDay, SaleItem
```

This is returning a table with the SaleItems organized properly, but the count is the total number sold, excluding the SaleDay attribute.

It's returning the total number of sales per item instead of only the sales on that day per item. So, if 7 pens were sold Monday and 6 on Tuesday it should return two tuples (7, Monday, Pen) and (6, Tuesday, pen). Currently, its returning (13, Monday, pen) and (13, Tuesday, pen).

How can I fix this query?

Comment: Can you clarify more the problem please? I tried your query and it gave me the same result as the output image except the second and the third rows were ordered differently.

Comment: Im working on a larger set of data, and its returning the total number of sales per item, instead of only the sales on that day per item. So if 7 pens were sold monday, and 6 on tuesday, it should return two touples (7, Monday, Pen) and (6, tuesday, pen). Currently, its returning (13, monday, pen) and (13, tuesday, pen)

Comment: try to remove distinct and make it
COUNT(*) AS 'Number'

Comment: Edit. I figured out the problem. Thank you for your time... It was just a silly mistake.

Comment: @Duffluc You should write your answer and then accept it.

Comment: @AlVaz - The problem obviously isn't with the query.  His data was probably different than he expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You complecated your question, by next simply show the input & output so you will get answer faster, any way, here is your solution: you don't need the distinct

```
SELECT SaleItem AS 'Item Sold', 
       SaleDay AS 'Item Sell Day', 
       COUNT(SaleItem) AS 'Number'
FROM Sales
GROUP BY SaleDay, SaleItem
```